# Convert all values of all properties to lower-case in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, lowercase

I have various nodes with different labels of the form:

```
(n:Label)
n.Name='ABS'
n.sample='ajx'
```

I want to change all the attribute values to lower-case. ie the result for the above should be:

```
(n:Label)
n.Name='abs'
n.sample='ajx'
```

I have tried the following...

```
match(n:Label) SET n.Name`=toLower(n.Name)
```

But this query only updates attributes one at a time. Is there a way to change all attributes simultaneously in a single query.

Comment: So have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to get properties 1 by 1, but that is tedious and so wanting to know if their is a smarter query.

Comment: You should mention the query you tried in the post.

Comment: match(n:Label)
SET n.Name`=toLower(n.Name)

This will change only 1 attribute. Is there a way to change all attributes together.

Comment: which version of neo4j are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the help of [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). Specifically `apoc.create.setProperty` procedure. This query should work:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, [x IN keys(n) 
        WHERE n[x] =~ '.*'
] as props
UNWIND props as p
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, p, toLower(n[p])) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

This query match all nodes of your graph and get the string properties of each node. After it `apoc.create.setProperty` is called for each property passing as new value `toLower(node[property])`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!